# Writing a language agnostic API?

Tags: c++, api, language-agnostic, desktop-application

I'm planning on writing a C++ program which is heavily influenced by plugin modules. Initially I had only thought of making the APi available as an abstract class that others extend. After talking to someone they mentioned that I should think about making it available in a language agnostic way.

**How do I effectively expose an API in a manner that any language can use it?**

The solution that I could come up with was having the C++ API like I originally intended, for C++ directly and CLI languages (C#, F, etc) and then a sort of document and executable combination. Where expected input is described in the document and then the executable is started (via console/terminal) I would give parameters given as start up commands. This would theoretically work but doesn't sound like a standard solution too me. **How is this done in other desktop software?**

Comment: Are RESTful architectures relevant? [Stack Overflow RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Comment: Protocol Buffers is typically named as a silver bullet for API, because it reduces the message communication down to two parts: (1) the protocol, (2) the exchange of byte arrays.

Comment: Well I thought about doing a REST thing, but the issue I have with that is that I would have many different things that implement the API that I would have to track and tell what to do and they would all be sitting on the computer running waiting for a call for the duration that the program is running. One implemented API could be doing multiple things at a time. I guess I could pass along an ID for the work that is being done and reference that when asking for status updates and giving specific instructions but that would become complicated and error prone extremely quickly.

Comment: @user3797758: What kind of library do you have in  mind? Please edit your question to tell more. What domain? What kind of users and usage?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Each API implementation would be responsible for doing a processing task. So there could be 1-2 things doing this or hundreds (in theory). This would involve giving input and some settings and essentially saying go, then waiting for the result. Ideally I would only have the same amount of API implementations processing as the computer has cores. So some of the API implementations wouldn't actually be used while some will see heavy usage. This is why I don't really like the REST idea since most a lot of the time there would be lots of programs sittings around listening...

Comment: Please **edit your question**

Comment: BTW, the above comment don't tell much. What domain  (selling machine, weather forecast, image processing, speech recognition, word processing, social network, ...) and what kind of software is it about... "processing task" means absolutely nothing and could apply to every piece of software. "Desktop software" is also too broad.

Comment: @Basile - Do you know what a 'plugin' is? The question asked seems pretty obvious. Most people write plugins expecting the plugin to be written in a specific language. This question is asking how to write a plugin without relying on the plugin being written in a specific language. The domain or task doesn't matter. What matters is how to communicate between different pieces of code running in the same process where the plugin code can be dynamically added to the application and do it in such a way that doesn't force the plugin to be implemented in a specific language. Good question.

Comment: I take my "question seems obvious" comment back. After reading someone else's comment, I went back and reread the OP's question more closely and now I'm confused because they mention 'plugin' but then seem to describe something totally different for what they want.

Comment: @Dunk nope, you had it in your second to last comment. That's basically what the question is about. Sorry if I didn't make that more obvious :(

Comment: Yes, a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) is dynamically loaded at runtiume (by `dlopen`on POSIX). Notice that the question did not mention any. And language or domain to matter a lot in practice

Comment: BTW, I added in my answer the reasons why the OP should improve a lot his question (which, in its current form, should be closed as too broad)

Comment: @user3797758 -I think your question is very good if it is indeed what I originally thought you asked. Is it possible to take I wrote in my comment and use it to clarify what you are specifically asking? I am kind of stumped at providing a solution to that question. Every idea I come up with seems to require the plugin having its own thread/process in order to work:( At that point, it is a huge stretch to still call it a plugin.

Comment: @Dunk I kind of want to make it a separate question now because this question already has a bunch of good answers covering just APIs and it would be a shame to undermine the validity of them by substantially changing to original question. What do you think?

Comment: @user3797758 The solution that you have come up with is effectively a [command shell (see Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot do that because some languages implementations could have an [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) different and incompatible with the C one.

On current systems, C is very common and most (but not all) language implementations have an ABI and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) compatible with the one from C. Notice that it is a property of the implementation (your C compiler and your operating system), not of the programming language.

Also, some languages have different and incompatible views on [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) (look into [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) and [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), Goroutines in [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)), or backtracking and [cut operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming)) in [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog), [CLIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) rules, concurrent actor languages, ....). I'm not sure you'll be able to design something which easily fits all of them (and that could impact the FFI requirements of implementation of these languages).

If using C++, beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and of exception handling. (e.g. C `longjmp` is not friendly with C++ exceptions). [Dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) facilities like [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) are relevant to name mangling. So prefer an API using `extern "C"` functions. [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) could be inspirational (it is coded in C++ but has a C friendly API) and perhaps useful (you could consider runtime generation of glue code).

Memory management (notably with [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))) is also an issue. Study for examples [foreign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) interface [of Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html) and [of SBCL](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Foreign-Function-Interface) and [of Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4) and of [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/learn/). Look into [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). Some languages also want [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) or [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) facilities (even for foreign data). Read also about [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating).

You could provide some reflection facilities (e.g an API to query your API, e.g. like [GTK introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection)). You might try to provide a generic closure mechanism like [in  GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Closures.html)-s.

You could use (or customize or adapt) code generators like [SWIG](http://swig.org/). You might consider compiler plugins (e.g. [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions).

If you have a wide and complex API (hundreds of public functions or data types) consider at least providing a machine readable form of it, e.g. some database or XML or JSON from which automatic glue code could be generated.

### There is [**no silver bullet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

<sup>NB. Better make your stuff [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You might get outside contributions and you'll need outside help to interface your thing with many programming languages, including some that you don't even know. [Open source](http://opensource.org/) is a good way to counter [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) (since you and other contributors can dive into the implementation source code). Given the variety of programming languages, **you will need *outside* help** (as soon as your API is successful)</sup>

---

## why the question don't make any sense

I asked several times the OP to give much more context and motivation, and to explain the domain for which the library is written, and the context in which that library would be developped. Sadly I've got no answers at all.

**The applicative domain** (e.g. high speed frequency trading, software for dentists, selling machine, weather forecast, image processing, speech recognition, word processing, social network, static source code analysis ...) ***matters* practically *a lot***, because it defines what programming languages are likely to be considered and what [programming paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) is probably used. For instance, an image processing library is very unlikely to need to be interfaced to [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)) or [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq), but probably would be used from C or C++ applications. Business software is often written in Java (and older ones was in Cobol) so needs to be interfacable to [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or JVM. Static source code analysis software is very likely to use some theorem prover (so Ocaml or Common Lisp or Haskell is important to them, and they need to be garbage-collection friendly). And so on. Sometimes, [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (including RPC, MPI, web services, RESTful applications) can be used, but at other times it is not efficient or not convenient enough. **Details and context are *very* important** and we don't know them.

The question mentions "desktop software", but that just means today something having a native (non-Web) [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) used with a mouse and a large enough color screen (the dentist software, the software for managing my bank accounts, your favorite game software, the word processor, a web browser are all desktop software, but their main commonality is just having a GUI). Using [Qt](http://qt.io/) (a very powerful GUI cross-platform toolkit for C++) facilitates the development of such things. And quite often a library used on desktop (think of XML or JSON libraries like [Xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) and [JsonCPP](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), machine learning libraries like [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), HTTP client libraries like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), numerical computation libraries like [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) or [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/), etc...) don't even care about GUI (but it could care about response time -having functions returning in less than 0.4 seconds- and thread friendliness), because the application (not a reusable library) would care about GUI itself.

The question mentions [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), but these are simply compiled software components which get [dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) at runtime (thus increasing the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) loading them), using e.g. [`dlopen` on POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) (and probably [`LoadLibrary` on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx), which I don't know at all). Notice that the JVM don't use (Java-coded) plugins but [dynamically loaded classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader), and speaking of plugins don't make sense with JavaScript or with Common Lisp (or most languages having a `compile` or  [`eval`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) primitive). So the mention of plugins don't means much (both Firefox browser and GCC compiler accept plugins, for very different reasons).

**Without a lot more additional details** (including applicative domain, context, motivation ...) **the current question don't make any sense**. I offer to delete my answer if that helps in closing the question in its current form.

<sup>PS. I don't know and never used Windows (but I use Unix since 1987, and Linux since 1993), but that is an unimportant detail.</sup>

Comment: I would like to add that most languages, even if their ABI is not compatible with C, will still be able to use it with special syntax(to annotate the types and functions) or with some FFI library. This is because C libraries are so common - and also very simple. No need to support classes, overloading, exceptions or managed memory - just locate the function by **un**mangled name and pass it some arguments.

Comment: Reading your answer I went like "yes, mmmh, yeah, probably, correct" and then ... I saw that teddy bear logo and for god's sake, yet another rant on free software. Maybe it's just me, but you could use those three lines to actually answer the question instead of (sigh) proposing to patch leaky abstractions with free software.

Comment: There is no generic answer to such an ill-defined question. And there are many programming languages, some with implementations having weird calling or FFI conventions; I don't even believe that a universal API or library is possible

Comment: Would the "execute executable from command line/terminal" not get around quite a few of the points that you have mentioned? As long as there is some standard that all of the executable arguments I should be able to call them and get around memory management (since it's not my application and will free its memory when it is done) and any error that it has would be limited to just that process, no?

Comment: It really depends. Some applications need a lot of state and sharing that state between several commands might  not be easy.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tibo: This strikes me as a little bit of sort-of topical information as an excuse to (yet again) post your favorite rant, regardless of its being irrelevant to the question.

Comment: But the original question makes in fact little sense. Writing something for every programming language (actually language *implementation*) is unrealistic. Assuming the OP's software is successful (which is unlikely) he will need outside help for interfacing it to obscure languages implementations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There is a huge difference between writing something for every language implementation and building something language agnostic. Also, what the hell has Open Source/Free Software to do with this? You can't solve abstraction issues by just pushing it to Open Software. This makes no sense in my book. The bulk of the answer is good but those ending lines are like a kick on the bucket of milk. If the question makes little sense, refrain to answer and ask for clarification.

Comment: The main point in providing an open source library is that other contributors (e.g. implementors of weird programming languages interfacing to your library) can study its implementation and understand corner cases issues. BTW I voted to close the question, asked in a comment for clarification and motivation, downvoted it. What kind I do more to get the question improved? Actually "language agnostic API" has little sense for me and is too presemptuous... And so is "API that *any* language can use"

Comment: Notice that even major free software libraries are not always interfaced to all (or simply to many) languages. An example is Qt (very widely used) for Ocaml (a niche language, but still quite used). You won't find serious bindings. Because the design of Qt is a good one, but not friendly with the Ocaml's one. Asking for an API usable for every language is as naive as asking for the perpetual motor. We would need some idea about the library the OP is considering to make, and we still dont have any.

Comment: I think you are right in that this question wasn't described in enough detail to cover plugins. I think that the best thing would be to open a new question since there are a lot of good answers for writing language agnostic APIs that would be a waste if this was deleted

Comment: If you think that, why don't you **edit your question** to improve it? You don't need to open a new one, but you should improve the current one... Is it so hard for you to edit your own question to improve and *motivate* it???

Comment: **The `edit` button appears under the question, left side. Please use it** (it looks like some hyperlink)  to improve and motivate your question

Comment: The best thing is **not** to open a new question, but rather to **edit the *current* question** to get it into some better shape.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's not appropriate for you to follow this user around the site, answering the same thing to their questions. Perhaps they wanted an answer from a different perspective. You love to insist that the question is poor, that the asker is uncooperative, etc. etc. But the lack of concrete detail suggests an interest in what sort of IPC/FFI/message passing options are available in general, rather than specific recommendations. Your condescending answer is an example of what makes SO a toxic community for beginners, as Jay's recent SO blog post discussed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm referring to https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 17):

*The accepted answer is more or less correct, but doesn't offer you anywhere to go if language independence is actually a burning issue for you. C++ is fairly callable from other languages (C#, Python, etc), and from the tone of your question it sounds more like a "nice to have", but let's pretend otherwise for a second.*

If platform/language independent communication is important to you, you should be using a [service-oriented architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture). **You should provide your C++ code as its own self contained service, which can respond to requests over technology agnostic network protocols.**

This is pretty common in the world of server applications and has a lot of benefits to do with architecture, scalability and protecting your applications from nasty memory bugs (+ stack overflows, etc) in other people's code.

It's a little bit more unusual for desktop apps though. I have seen it with [the Rider IDE](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/07/26/rider-the-story-so-far/), where they mainly use it for the architectural benefits of keeping their ReSharper product separate from their IDE product.

This is ultimately how you make things agnostic, but also represents a serious architectural change that has a lot of advantages and disadvantageous in multiple areas. Look into it and decide.

Comment: Wish I could star this answer

Answer (score 9):

Although none is literally 100% universal, there are a number of ways to make the API easily usable from a fairly wide variety of languages (more than most people usually care about, anyway).

The most obvious (and ubiquitous) form would be RPC, such as [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) or [Thrift](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift) (or, if you're using Windows, [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694505.aspx)).

These all work reasonably similarly: you define the API itself in an interface definition language (IDL). You then use a compiler to generate code for the client and/or server side of this interface. This will typically give you the skeleton of a server. You fill the actual functionality, compile it all up, and off you go.

Comment: Also, XPCOM. Much like COM, but open.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with the other answers in principle, I think the OP is expecting at least some starting points which can help OP's further search for an answer.

In-process

- Important consideration

  - Native code is architecture-specific. This means 32-bit and 64-bit can't mix in the same Windows process.
  - While pure .NET IL can be executed in either 32-bit or 64-bit environments, native code must be compiled individually for each architecture.
  - If these limitations are show-stoppers, you must use out-of-process approach instead.
- Win32 DLL

  - Export C-callable functions.
  - Can pass integer values, floating point values, arrays of primitives (including byte arrays), etc.
  - Be careful with "structs", make sure two pieces of communicating software agree on struct field alignment for each struct.
  - .NET users can use P/Invoke to call DLLs. This can be converted into a .NET wrapper, which can completely hide the native aspect of the underlying implementation.
- Microsoft COM

  - Mature, recommended
- .NET Interop using C++/CLI

  - Recommended if most users are on .NET

Out-of-process, same machine, non-communicating (no information exchange in the middle of execution)

- Command line application.

  - Communication happens via command-line arguments and files.
  - Using I/O redirection on Windows is not recommended because it is unreliable except for very simple ones. The documentation mentions deadlocks as a possibility.

Out-of-process, same machine, communicating

- Choice of running as Windows Application or as Windows Service
- Command line application plus any choice of inter-process communication. Refer to inter-process communication on Windows documentation.

  - Shared memory or inter-process memory-mapped file
  - Inter-process synchronization primitives (only for synchronization or semaphore needs)
  - Inter-process pipes
  - Over the file system. Synchronization (hand-off) must happen via one of the other means. Alternatively, repeatedly scan a folder for file changes at periodic intervals.
- WCF

Out-of-process, different machines, communicating

- Architectures

  - Server client architecture
  - Distributed architecture
- Writing an web service that runs under IIS
- Running as a Windows Service that communicates over TCP/IP
- Running as a Windows Service that communicates over WCF

Comment: Your answer is exclusively Windows centered, and Windows was not exactly mentioned in the question (even if F# or CLR is Windows mostly)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Since you have already listed options for Linux, I think my answer complements the Windows part. Though, I sincerely believe OP is indeed having Windows in mind. Also, my answer contains some options that are OS-agnostic as well. P/Invoke works for non-Microsoft CLI implementations (e.g. Mono, .NET Core, etc.) Let's not hijack OP's question for personal software-political expressions.

Comment: Yes, but you could at least mention Windows in your answer. Few things apply to Linux unchanged.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch did you not see the word "Windows" prefixed to every phrase where it is applicable?

Comment: I want to develop it on windows and aim for windows but use tech that can be used on linux too. So if in the future someone wants to run on linux I/they would only (theoretically) have to recompile

Comment: @user3797758 First spend some time with higher-up stakeholders to determine whether future requirements (e.g. next 2 years) will make out-of-process (or, over-the-network) necessary. If in-process is okay, then I'd recommend P/Invoke to a DLL (Windows) or SO (Linux). Basile's answer mentions a lot of tools that can generate wrapper / shim code to make this easier.

Answer (score 4):

To bring an "old-fashioned", but quite mature technology into the discussion:

CORBA allows you to define object-oriented APIs in a language-independent way (defines its own IDL = interface definition language). Language mappings are available for really all major languages (and even many exotic ones).

It supports local and remote inter-process communication (that's the typical use case), but server implementations can also exist in-process (then using direct method calls). The inter-process communication protocol is binary-based and quite fast.

At our company, we're still using it for performance-critical cases, and interoperability always worked (using mixtures of Java, C, C++, C# and CommonLisp). We've used CORBA for interfaces to partner companies, often not even knowing what programming language they used.

And maybe you've already used it without knowing. E.g. Java's RMI/IIOP is effectively CORBA.

Comment: yep i did though of corba as soon I red the title, whatever we think of CORBA, it definitively match the requirement of OP.